# Duplicate bibliography references in two languages

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I write a journal article and now I need to put references inside my document. I need to put two normative reference sections at the end of my article. References are same, but in first section it must be in russian in the first section and in english in the last.

Something like this:

[image]

I use `bibtex` and the `natbib` package. I create multiple `.bib` files where I put my bibliographies. Each language for each file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, russian]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{\parindent}{*3}{*2}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{\parindent}{*3}{*2}


\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.\hfill} 
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod~\cite{book1} tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit~\cite{book1, article1} in voluptate velit esse cillum~\cite{article1} dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \small
    \bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
    \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{Список литературы}} 
    \bibliography{biblio_ru}{}
    \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{References}} 
    \bibliography{biblio_en}{}

\end{document}
```

Here is a conent of my *.bib files.
biblio_ru.bib:

```
@book{book1,
    title = "Наименование книги 1",
    author = "Автор",
    editor = "Редактор",
    address = "Адрес",
    publisher = "Издптельство",
    year = 2012,
    numpages = 507,
    language = "russian"
}

@article{article1,
    title = "Наименование статьи",
    author = "Автор",
    editor = "Редактор",
    address = "Адрес",
    publisher = "Издательство",
    year = 2011,
    numpages = 837,
    language = "russian",
    edition = "Номер издания"
}
```

biblio_en.bib:

```
@book{book1,
    title = "Book name",
    author = "Book Author",
    editor = "Editor",
    address = "Address",
    publisher = "Publisher",
    year = 2012,
    numpages = 507,
    language = "english"
}

@article{article1,
    title = "Article name",
    author = "Author",
    editor = "Editor",
    address = "Address",
    publisher = "Publisher",
    year = 2011,
    numpages = 837,
    language = "english",
    edition = "Edition number"
}
```

The result I've got after using LaTeX + Bibtex:

[image]

What shall I do to create bibliography references in multiple languages?

Comment: I use _extarticle_ document class with _extsizes_ package

Comment: You can use `\selectlanguage{russian}`, `\printbibliography` and `\selectlanguage{english}`, `\printbibliography`. Problem: bib entry text isen't switching(you use only one bibfile). At the moment I can't help you. I will see if i find time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but maybe still useful: You can use `multibib` to obtain this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, russian]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}


\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{en}{english}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\cite{#1}\nociteen{#1}}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.\hfill}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod~\mycite{book1} tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit~\mycite{book1, article1} in voluptate velit esse
cillum~\mycite{article1} dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

\small
\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{Список литературы}} 
\bibliography{biblio_ru}{}
\bibliographystyleen{ugost2008}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{References}} 
\bibliographyen{biblio_en}{}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]